# CiviCRM and Webform Confirmation Page

Tags: webform-civicrm

Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 4.6

Using the Webform extension, which is amazing of course.  Is there a way to get the confirmation page to look like the page would be if somebody was using a native CiviCRM form.  For example for a new membership, it would show name, membership expiration date etc?  This does get emailed but sometimes our members don't get our emails, so it is nice to have a confirmation page they can print with these fields like you can in a CiviCRM form?

Might be obvious thing I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer will be primarily a drupal answer ie you need to get the tokens for the submission values on the confirmation page. The best recipe (untested by me) that I can see that doesn't involve a custom module is [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135209/webform-show-the-preview-page-on-confirmation-instead?rq=1)

Please report back how it goes.